# What function produces {0, -8, 8, -16, 16, ... }?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to figure out a function that produces the set of numbers {0, -8, 8, -16, 16, ... } when given the set of positive integers.  I'm having a hard time understanding what makes some results positive and some negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without partial definitions, and assuming $0\in \Bbb N$:
$$
f(n)=(-1)^n\cdot8\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil
$$

Answer (score 2):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define a function
\begin{equation}
 f(n) = \begin{cases}
        4n-4  & \text{ when } n  \text{ is odd}\\
        -4n & \text{ when } n  \text{ is even}.
        \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to find a formula for the sequence $\{ 0,8,8,16,16,\dots \}$ and a formula for the sequence $\{ 1,-1,1,\dots \}$. Then multiply the two of them.

A second hint: note that in my second sequence, each term is $-1$ times the previous term, and the terms start at $1$.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful.  So far I have the function f(n) = -8n, and I'm trying to figure out the second part.

Comment: I think I might have it. f(n) = -8n(-1)^n.

Hmm... Needs to work with only positive integers though.

Comment: @Carl Your formula for the second sequence is good. Your formula for the first sequence is not quite right: your first sequence is $\{ -8,-16,-24,\dots \}$. Notice that my first sequence only changes value when $n$ is even. This means it is really only a function of $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ (or $\lceil n/2 \rceil$).

Comment: Ahh, ok this makes sense now. Thanks a lot for your help. I have the function (−1)^n⋅8⌊(n/2)⌋

Answer (score 0):

Sure, how about

$$f(x) = 0, x = 1,$$

$$f(y) = 4(y - 1),$$ 
where $y > 0$ is odd, and

$$f(z) = -4z,$$
where $z > 0$ is even?